# assign value from a column to a variable and do arithmetic calculation

Tags: shell

I have a out.txt file having values like this:

```
39
45
44
55
50
```

I want to calculate the % increase from the 1st value (Ex: (45-39)*100/39 = 15.38%). So the output will be like this :

```
0%
15.38%
12.8%
41.03%
28.21%
```

So I wrote a bash script like this:

```
   *#!/bin/bash
    a=( `cat "out.txt"`)
    length=${#a[*]}
    echo $length
    x=${a[0]}
    echo $x
     for (( i = 1; i <= $length; i++))
  do
y=${a[$i]}
echo $y
diff= `echo "scale=2; ($y-$x)*100/$x" | bc`
    echo $diff
```

done

but this script is creating error like this:

(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    read first
    echo "0%"
    while read value; do
        printf "%.2f%%\n" $(bc <<< "100*($value-$first)/$first")
    done
} << END
39
45
44
55
50
END
```

results in

```
0%
15.38%
12.82%
41.03%
28.21%
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect line-endings in your `out.txt` file. The `^M` characters are carriage returns.

Run `dos2unix` to change it to use Unix line endings.

Also note that there should be no spaces on either side of the `=` sign when assigning a variable. You have one here:

```
diff= `echo "scale=2; ($y-$x)*100/$x" | bc`
```

Remove the space on the right of the `=` sign.